# Как адаптировать блоки?

Tags: html, html5, css3

Как можно адаптировать два блока или выразить пиксели в процентах?

Ширина контейнера - 1366px. В него входят два блока : первый - 908px, второй - 458px.

Вот примерный код для понятности :

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1366px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.header-block {
  height: 715px;
}
.header-block-left {
  width: 908px;
  height: 715px;
  float: left;
}
.header-block-left img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.header-block-right {
  width: 458px;
  height: 715px;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-block container">
  <div class="header-block-left">
    <img src="img/block-1.png">
  </div>

  <div class="header-block-right"></div>
```

Получается неравномерная высота и при уменьшении/увеличении разрешения, блоки едут.

Comment: что Вы подразумеваете под *выразить пиксели в процентах*? Блоки едут, т.к. `width` у Вас в `px`. Просто подставьте `width` в процентах, `header-block-left` - 66,47% или 66%, `header-block-right` - 33.53% или 34%

Comment: Я полагаю, что можно сделать данную разметку на flexbox и это данную решит проблем. Если такое решение подойдёт, могу добавить ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Разделите 908 на 1366 и передвиньте вправо запятую на две цифры 908:1366=0,6647..= 66,5% и так далее.

Comment: *передвиньте вправо запятую на две цифры* - в данном случае это называется "умножить на сто".